# Can the HTML5 Filesystem API help me edit .html files on my own harddrive without a server?

Tags: html, html5-filesystem

I'm confused about the point of the HTML5 Filesystem API.

As far as I can tell, the way to refer to the content of one of the sandboxed files created with the File API requires reference to a domain name.

"Using the HTML5 Filesystem API" has this to say under "Security Considerations":

> Leakage or erasure of private data—this is mitigated by limiting the scope of the HTML5 filesystem to a chroot-like, origin-specific sandbox. Applications cannot access another domain/origin’s filesystem.

But what exactly is an "origin"? As far as I can tell that book doesn't define them. It appears to me that an origin must contain a domain name, even if that domain is `localhost`.

Is this the case? If it is, that sucks. It means that yet again we can't build editors that can edit local files. There are security considerations, certainly, but isn't it at least part of the *plan* to make it possible to edit local files? Are HTML5 APIs targeted exclusively at content on the internet or at people who know how to set up a local server?

Comment: What is so wrong about running a server on `localhost`? Small and quick HTTP servers are the norm these days...

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it, I do it. The problem is that I'm trying to write applications for people who aren't going to understand that. And I definitely don't want to be responsible for helping them do it.

Answer (score 3):

[This is the full definition of origin in HTML5](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/origin-0.html), which refers to [RFC 6454](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6454).  The significant bit as far as you're concerned is:

> If the two origins are scheme/host/port triples, the two origins
> are the same if, and only if, they have identical schemes, hosts,
> and ports.

It's true that this won't let you browse the file system from JavaScript but if you think about it this is a good thing.  If it was possible to browse your filesystem with JavaScript then any web page you visit could potentially steal all your files without you knowing.  However that's not quite the same thing as being unable to access files, there's been a way to access files in HTML for years and it looks like this:

```
<input type="file" id="inputField">
```

HTML5 allows you to access any files selected with this element without having to roundtrip back to the server.

```
var inputElement = document.getElementById("inputField");
inputElement.addEventListener("change", handleFiles, false);

function handleFiles() {
    var fileList = this.files;

    for (var i = 0, numFiles = files.length; i < numFiles; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        //do stuff with file
    }
}
```

There are some other good examples in [this MSN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications) which I stole the above (untested) code from.

If you use [HTML5 Offline Apps](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html) you can access a web server exactly once then shut that server down and continue to use the app to edit any files you attach to it through the methods described above.